# validate multiple email addresses in one input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am accepting multiple email address in an input field.I want to validate following : email address has to separated by space,email addresses shouldn't be more than 5,and email address shouldn't be available in database
how can i do this by using jquery or javascript,ajax

Comment: What have you done so far ? Please mention over there so we can help you.

Comment: You should atleast include some thing you've tried so far with your problem.

Comment: i have completed back coding only.now i have started the validation part

Comment: i have added an input field only

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function checkEmails(email) {
    email = email .replace(/\ /g, '');
    var emails = email.split(","),
        status = true,
        badEmail = '';

    $.each(emails, function(i,v) {
        if (!validateEmail(v)) {
            status = false,
            badEmail = badEmail+v+' ';
        }
    });

    if(status == true) {
     //All emails are right 
    }

    else {
        //Some emails are wrong
        // emails list are badEmail
    }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
```